# Delete document in CosmosDB through azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Reading the Azure portal I've understood how to make a `POST`, `PUT` and `GET` operation with CosmosDB through the Azure Functions. But deleting, I don't understand how to do this.

Which bindings should I use. Should it occur either through sql query or collection's method, like Remove()?

```
        [**FunctionName**("EmployeeDocumentDB")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", "put", "delete", Route = "EmployeeDocumentDB/partitionkey/{key}/id/{id}")]HttpRequestMessage req,
        [DocumentDB(
        databaseName: "MyDatabase",
        collectionName: "MyCollection",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBEmulator")] ICollector<Person> outputDocument,
        TraceWriter log)
    {
        dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<Person>();

        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
```

Comment: Where did you learn the PUT at? and did you get an answer that worked for you on delete? I'm stuck

Comment: Same here stuck on delete and put

Answer (score 3):

I combined:

- HTTP trigger
- CosmoDB DocumentClient Input
- CosmoDB Input with look up ID from query string

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "delete")] HttpRequest req,
            [CosmosDB(databaseName: "storage", collectionName: "pizza", Id = "{Query.id}", PartitionKey = "{Query.storeId}", ConnectionStringSetting = "..."] Document document,
            [CosmosDB(databaseName: "storage", collectionName: "pizza", ConnectionStringSetting = ...)] DocumentClient client)
        {
            string storeId = req.Query["storeId"];

            if(document == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeId))
                return new BadRequestResult();

            await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(document.SelfLink, new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(storeId) });

            return new OkResult();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by binding directly to the `DocumentClient` itself, and delete the Document programatically.

```cs
[FunctionName("DeleteDocument")]
public static async Task Run(
    [TimerTrigger("00:01", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timer,
    [DocumentDB] DocumentClient client,
    TraceWriter log)
{
    var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("ItemDb", "ItemCollection");
    var documents = client.CreateDocumentQuery(collectionUri);

    foreach (Document d in documents)
    {
        await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(d.SelfLink);
    }
}
```

See [CosmosDBSamples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/src/ExtensionsSample/Samples/CosmosDBSamples.cs)

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to leverage the stored procedures programming for Azure Cosmos DB and delete the documents inside a single stored procedure in batch for better performance (network traffic latency, store overhead for transactions, etc.). For more details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#introduction-to-stored-procedure-and-udf-programming).

For creating the stored procedure, you could create it for your collection on Azure Portal in a simple way. And you could follow the sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/bulkDelete.js) for deleting documents in batch for a given query.

For your azure function, you could call the code below for executing the stored procedure to delete the documents in batch:

```html
StoredProcedureResponse<object> result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<object>(
    UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("MyDatabase", "MyCollection", "bulkDeleteSproc"), 
    "SELECT c._self FROM c WHERE c.founded_year = 2008");
```